# Hiragana long ō: spelling: おう versus おお?

Tags: hiragana, kana

I would like to know what the difference is between the two spellings of the long o (ō), in hiragana, namely おう (ou) and おお (oo). Are these pronounced the same?

If so, then why does Japanese have these two different spellings for the same long o vowel?

Also, when transcribing from a textbook that uses romaji to teach Japanese, and entering the characters at the keyboard, is there a set criterion for curbing which combination I should be using (and dots it matter)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wikipedia page, the difference is due to historical reasons.

お段の仮名の長音の場合には、おのかわりにうを添える
例：こうしん（コーシン／更新）

お段の仮名でも、後続する音が歴史的仮名遣いで「ほ」または「を」であった場合には、「お」を添える
例：おおきい（大きい）
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%95%B7%E9%9F%B3

Words that were originally written with を or ほ are now written with お.
Example: おおきい (大きい)

All other words are now written with う
Example: こうしん (更新)

Comment: You haven't answered whether the is the same (long o), our whether a diphthong pronunciation (consisting of two vowels is also possible, as :/ the Chinese 口 (kou))? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about the pronunciation. I think it is the same, but I have heard people saying O-o-sa-ka, for example.