# Can't find adjective in dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I am looking for the adjective jōzu / boozy in my Takoboto dictionary, to learn further information, or its kanji, but cannot find it.

Can someone help me develop a strategy for looking up and finding adjectives in a dictionary?

[image: dictionary entries for joozu] [image: textbook entry]

Comment: Hint: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39927/hiragana-long-%c5%8d-spelling-%e3%81%8a%e3%81%86-versus-%e3%81%8a%e3%81%8a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn Hepburn romanization if you want to use romaji. Your textbook uses a non-standard type of romanization. Better yet, just learn the kana. The word is 上手｛じょうず｝.

Comment: I think that *jōzu* is in fact Hepburn romanization, as //ou// gets romanized as *ō* unless there is either a word boundary between //o// and //u// (e.g. 子牛), or the //u// is the (inflecting) ending of a verb (e.g. 迷う).

Answer (score 0):

The adjective is actually spelled as jouzu in the dictionary. As with many oo combinations, one has to try on as well, as per [this post.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39927/18183)